# In an SBT multi project build, how to reference projects from other folders?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to tidy up my huge SBT multi-project build. Currently, I have everything in one big SBT file, but I am trying to fan this out into several directories.

In a nutshell, this is my folder structure:

```
root
+-foo
| +-foofoo
| | +-build.sbt
| +-build.sbt
| |
| +-foobar
| | +-build.sbt
| +-build.sbt
| |
| bar
| +-barfoo
| | +-build.sbt
| +-build.sbt
| |
+-build.sbt
```

In `root/build.sbt` I have:

```
lazy val root = project.
  in(file(".")).
  settings(publishArtifact := false).
  aggregate(foo,
            bar)

lazy val foo = project in file("foo")
lazy val bar = project in file("bar")
```

In `foo/build.sbt` I have:

```
lazy val foo = project.
  in(file(".")).
  settings(publishArtifact := false).
  aggregate(foofoo,
            foobar)

lazy val foofoo = project in file("foofoo")
lazy val foobar = project in file("foobar")
```

In `bar/build.sbt` I have:

```
lazy val bar = project.
  in(file(".")).
  settings(publishArtifact := false).
  aggregate(barfoo)

lazy val barfoo = project in file("barfoo")
```

Now, I want `barfoo` to depend on `foofoo`, so, naïvely, I defined in `barfoo/build.sbt`:

```
lazy val barfoo = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(foofoo)
```

But when running `sbt compile` it complains it can't find `foofoo`.

So, how to correctly reference these intra-project dependencies?

Currently the only way I can think of is to run `sbt foo/publishLocal` first and then add this as `libraryDependencies`. Is this the only way or is there another one?

## Followup 1

After some digging, I read that `ProjectRef` should do the trick, but this gives me another error:

I have some common dependencies in a `Dependencies.scala` object in my `project` subfolder. This is found by all subprojects. However when I define:

```
lazy val foofoo = ProjectRef(file("foo/foofoo"), "foofoo")
lazy val barfoo = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(foofoo)
```

I get this:

```
C:\Somewhere\bar\barfoo\build.sbt:1: error: not found: object Dependencies
import Dependencies._
       ^
```

## Followup 2

I got it to work but I don't know if this is the right approach, so I leave it here but don't post it as an answer:

```
lazy val foofoo = project in file("../../foo/foofoo")
lazy val barfoo = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(foofoo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you more or less already answered it yourself but nevertheless here is my way of doing it:

```
lazy val core = RootProject(file("../../../myCoreProject/"))
lazy val main = Project(
   id = "mySubProject", 
   base = file(".")
).dependsOn(core)
```

where `core` is the project I want to reference. This is in the `build.sbt` file of the subproject, which resides three directories further down the filetree.

See: [RootProject](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/api/sbt/RootProject.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks other things. I have objects like `Dependencies.scala`, `Settings.scala` in my `project` folder, and reference stuff from there (i.e., common versions for dependencies). As soon as I use `RootProject` or `ProjectRef`, these are not found any more in the subprojects.

Comment: Addendum: When trying to use this, I have to use `RootProject(file("myCoreProject"))` because in my case, sbt uses the root folder of the project as a reference, even in subprojects.

Comment: Ah that is interesting. I did not know that. But using a common `Dependencies.scala` certainly sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I also dug around the net quite heavily on that but everything about multi-project builds boils down to use one single sbt file. Maybe I'll split this big project to multiple smaller ones, I think that's the lesser evil...

Comment: Well in my case I have a core project and 2 seperate subprojects, which both use the 'core'. Works quite well so far (but as I said I don't use a common dependencies file like yours, which means I have a lot of duplicated dependencies atm). I feel like there is not that many people using scalajs for huge projects yet so the stuff one can find on the net feels very limited - I hope that'll change in the future though.

Comment: In my case, I have core project and multiple subprojects, and some subprojects use other subprojects.